# How to use built-in Javascript extension to automatically find symbols in a JS file when developing a custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a custom VSCode extension. I need to grab symbols (e.g. variables, functions, etc.) from a Javascript file that the user is currently on to find their definitions and do something with them when the user hovers over. Does VSCode / the JS extension expose an API to find these symbols and their definitions without doing so manually?

None of the API (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) seems to expose this functionality.

I've tried looking at the built in JS/TS extension to see what kind of API it exposes but found nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```typescript
async function getSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument): Promise<vscode.DocumentSymbol[]> {
    return await commands.executeCommand<vscode.DocumentSymbol[]>('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', document.uri) || [];
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands